# Write INSERT statements with values next to column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, insert

When writing an INSERT statement with a lot of columns, it would be nice to have the value next to the column name like in an UPDATE statement. Something like:

```
insert into myTable
set
  [col1] = 'xxx',
  [col2] = 'yyy',
  [col3] = 42
  etc...
```

Are there any tricks to mimic this?

I thought I was onto something with this:

```
insert into myTable
select
  [col1] = 'xxx',
  [col2] = 'yyy',
  [col3] = 42
  etc...
```

But the aliases aren't actually being associated with the insert table's columns and if someone added a new column to the table it could really screw things up. Anyone have any other ideas of how one could do this?

Comment: This is one of the true annoyances of SQL. ANd it causes errors as it is easy to get the order changed by accident and if the datatypes are compatible, you are suddenly putting the phone number into the email column with no errors.

Comment: I too really wish that SQL provided a way to do this. It would improve readability dramatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest you'll get would be to specify the columns on the insert (this will protect you from your concern about a new column being added) and alias the values on the select (which gives you some degree of self-documenting code).

```
insert into myTable
    ([col1], [col2], [col3])
    select 'xxx' as [col1], 'yyy' as [col2], 42 as [col3]
```

Comment: Aliases are not required, assuming the select order matches the into column order. Though they might help keep things clearly indicated. :)

Comment: @Rocky Madden: Agreed. As I indicated in my answer, I included the aliases more as an attempt at self-documenting the code.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that it was clear to the OP. As usual, you were right on the money!

Answer (score 1):

For big inserts, I've done fancy (and perhaps overfly fussy) layouts.  Some examples:

```
INSERT MyTable ( MyTableId,        Name,             Description,      SomeStringData1
                ,SomeStringData2,  SomeStringData3,  SomeStringData4,  MoreStringData1
                ,MoreStringData2,  MoreStringData3,  MoreStringData4,  SomeNumericData1
                ,SomeNumericData2, SomeNumericData3, SomeNumericData4, MoreNumericData1
                ,MoreNumericData2, MoreNumericData3, MoreNumericData4, BigBlobAA
                ,BigBlobBB,        EnteredAtDate,    UpdatedAtDate,    RevisedAtDate
                ,NeedAnotherDate )
 values
               ( @MyTableId,        @Name,             @Description,      @SomeStringData1
                ,@SomeStringData2,  @SomeStringData3,  @SomeStringData4,  @MoreStringData1
                ,@MoreStringData2,  @MoreStringData3,  @MoreStringData4,  @SomeNumericData1
                ,@SomeNumericData2, @SomeNumericData3, @SomeNumericData4, @MoreNumericData1
                ,@MoreNumericData2, @MoreNumericData3, @MoreNumericData4, @BigBlobAA
                ,@BigBlobBB,        @EnteredAtDate,    @UpdatedAtDate,    @RevisedAtDate
                ,@NeedAnotherDate )
```

This works if you're pretty darn certain that you wont ever be inserting columns or otherwise modifying what is being inserted. It gets gets everything on one screen, and makes it fairly simple to pick out what value goes into which column.

If inserted values are likely to change or are complex (such as case statements), I do the following (outdent all but every fifth item):

```
INSERT MyTable
  (
     MyTableId
    ,Name
    ,Description
    ,SomeStringData1
   ,SomeStringData2
    ,SomeStringData3
    ,SomeStringData4
    ,MoreStringData1
    ,MoreStringData2
   ,MoreStringData3
    ,MoreStringData4
    ,SomeNumericData1
    ,SomeNumericData2
    ,SomeNumericData3
   ,SomeNumericData4
    ,MoreNumericData1
    ,MoreNumericData2
    ,MoreNumericData3
    ,MoreNumericData4
   ,BigBlobAA
    ,BigBlobBB
    ,EnteredAtDate
    ,UpdatedAtDate
    ,RevisedAtDate
   ,NeedAnotherDate
  )
 values
  (
     MyTableId
    ,Name
    ,Description
    ,SomeStringData1
   ,SomeStringData2
    ,SomeStringData3
    ,SomeStringData4
    ,MoreStringData1
    ,MoreStringData2
   ,MoreStringData3
    ,MoreStringData4
    ,case
       when something then 'A'
       when orOther   then 'B'
       else 'Z'
     end
    ,SomeNumericData2
   ,SomeNumericData3
    ,SomeNumericData4
    ,MoreNumericData1
    ,MoreNumericData2
    ,MoreNumericData3
   ,MoreNumericData4
    ,BigBlobAA
    ,BigBlobBB
    ,EnteredAtDate
    ,UpdatedAtDate
   ,RevisedAtDate
    ,NeedAnotherDate
  )
```

(After adding that CASE statement, I "counted indents" to make sure I had everything lined up properly.)

It takes a bit of effort to get things layed out properly, but it can make maintenance, support, and subsequent modification simpler.

Comment: I'm with you, personally, I f I havea lot of columns I line oup the columns three or four to a line and make the line of the selct or values clause match exactly. I still have to manually chack, but at least it easier when the columns are lined up correctly as in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no.  The syntax for SQL INSERT is to the list all the columns, then all the values.  Even if you could find a trick to express the syntax the way you want it would be non-portable and confusing to the next person to have to maintain your code.

If you want a visual mapping of columns to values use something along the lines of Philip's answer, above.  But please don't spend any of your valuable time to make your code avoid the standard syntax.

Comment: Good point, I sometimes look for ways to make things nicer for myself, but should never do so with the side-effect of making my code unreadable or confusing.

Comment: I appreciate where you're coming from, and I often doing layouts like Philip suggested (except I try to stay on one line so the value is directly under the column name, even if the line is very, very long).

Answer (score 0):

Once you want to insert multiple rows simultaneously, using either 2008 style row constructors, or using the older `union all` syntax, you tend to be thankful that you *don't* have to specify the column names for every row.

2008 row constructors:

```
insert into myTable (col1,col2,col3)
values ('xxx','yyy',42),
('abc','def',19),
('HJK','www',-4)
```

UNION all:

```
insert into myTable (col1,col2,col3)
select 'xxx','yyy',42 union all
select 'abc','def',19 union all
select 'HJK','www',-4
```

Comment: Yes, I can see not wanting column names if you're inserting multiple rows, but I was referring to inserting a single row with lots and lots of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution I came up with was the following:

```
insert into MyTable
(ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ColumnName3)
values
(/*ColumnName1*/'value1', /*ColumnName2*/'value2', /*ColumnName3*/'value3')
```

Answer (score -3):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2, col3)
 SELECT 'xxx' [col1], 'yyy' [col2], '42' [col3]
```

Comment: This is the same as the example I gave. I don't want this because if someone adds a column to myTable it could potentially insert data into the wrong column.

Comment: YOu should under no circumstance ever do an insert without specifying the columsn inthe insert. This is bad bad bad code.